# a way to calculate derivative of an integral over a ball of any continuous function of a vector

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

Let $B_t = \{(x_1, x_2)\ |\ x_1^2 + x_2^2 \le t^2\}, t \in [0..1]$

Let $f \in C(B_1) $

Let $F(t) = \iint\limits_{B_t}f(x_1, x_2)dx_1dx_2$

**1) Calculate $F'$**

If a function $f(x_1, x_2)$ was given, then the task is clear.
But when $f$ is any function... I even have no idea where to start from.
The book(and the very chapter) where this problem is taken from is in Russian, so I'm not sure if I'll translate terminology correctly. But this is something like "change of variables for injective vector mappings":

$\int\limits_{\vec{g}(B)}f(\vec{y})d\vec{y} = \int\limits_{B}f(\vec{g}(\vec{x}))|\frac{\partial{g_1}...\partial{g_m}}{\partial{x_1}...\partial{x_m}}|d\vec{x}$

This is supposed to help in solving this problem in some way, but i have no clue how...

**2) is $f \in C(B_1) $ a typo? Shouldn't it be $f \in C(B_t) $?**

Comment: An answer to part two seems that it most likely is not a typo, but even if it was it probably would not make a large difference unless t=0

Comment: Regarding first part it seems like integration by change of variables. The route of attack seems to be to express the $B_t$ in polar coordinates, then express the integral over the ball as iterated integral over radius and angle, and this can then probably be evaluated by some simple theorem which I do not know of the top of my head, but I know that one such can be found in Apostols Calculus 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of answer is as follows. We are taking a transformation of rectangle and transforming it onto a disk by  $g:[0,t] \times [0, 2\pi] \to B_t$ defined by:

$$g(r, \theta) = [r\cos{(\theta), r\sin{(\theta)}}]^T$$

Now we use this transformation $g$ as given in your formula and get :

$$\int\limits_{B_t}^{}f(x,y) \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y = \int\limits_{0}^{t}\int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi}  f(r \cos{\theta}, r \sin{\theta}) r 
  \mathrm{d}r \mathrm{d}\theta$$

Let:

$$u(r) = \int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi} f(r \cos{\theta}, r \sin{\theta}) r \mathrm{d}\theta$$

Now :

$$F(t) = \int\limits_{0}^{t} u(r) \mathrm{d}r$$

And here we can apply Leibniz Integral Rule ( which you can find on Wikipedia ), and which seems easy from here on